# Separated application.properties in spring-boot multi module application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm building a **spring-boot multi module application**, and I want each module to be able to contain the related application.properties to its domain.

I'm using gradle buildSrc approach for multi module.

Structure is something like:

```
root-project
   main-module
     src/main/java 
       MainApplication.java
     src/main/resources
       application.properties <-- This one is correctly read

   subproject
     src/main/java 
     src/main/resources
       application.properties <-- I want the main spring-boot app to pick this properties as well
```

Any way I could make this work?

Comment: No. Basically due to how classloading works. It will only read the first `application.properties` from the root of the class path. Which always will be the one from your main module. If you want dedicated properties you will need to either load them through `@PropertySource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by providing the location of file while running the application.

```
  $ java -jar my_app.jar --spring.config.location=optional:classpath:/{path_to_main_module}/application.properties,optional:classpath:/{path_to_sub_module}/application.properties
```

But what you are trying is not standard way. Other option could to add needed properties from sub module to main module properties file.

You can get more information about how to externalize config files from spring doc [Spring Externalize Config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config)